# Passing child's events to a parent

Tags: reactjs

I am enhancing a textarea with autocomplete functionality like this:

```
<MentionAutocomplete ref="autocomplete">
  <Textarea ref="editor"/>
</MentionAutocomplete>
```

The idea is that `MentionAutocomplete` can use any thing like `textarea` or `input` in itself and still work.

This works nicely and its achieved by the autocomplete listening to keyboard events like this:

```
<div 
  className="MentionAutocomplete"
  onKeyDown={this.handleKey}
  onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
>
  {this.props.children}
  {this.renderAutocomplete()}
</div>
```

But I recently ran into an issue, where the autocomplete complains that `field.value` is `undefined`. I am assuming that the `Textarea` component might be doing something, or there might be a browser extension messing with it.

So ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
var self = this;

<MentionAutocomplete ref="autocomplete">
  <Textarea ref="editor" onKeyUp={(event) => self.refs.autocomplete.keyUp(event) } />
</MentionAutocomplete>
```

But I am wondering, is this the right approach? Is there a better way?

Comment: Where are you using `field.value`?

Comment: in `handleKeyUp`, there is `e.target.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can define the event handler on the parent, and pass it through to the child:

```
<div className="MentionAutocomplete">
  {React.cloneElement(this.props.children {handleEvent: this.handleEvent})}
</div>
```

`handleEvent` here is a function you define on the parent where you can pass the event or whatever and is available on the child through `this.props`.

Another approach that seems a good fit for what you're trying to create would be to create a [higher order component](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775) which essentially wraps a component with another to add functionality.

Comment: Thanks, thats very clean approach, although its cloning the element, I like the fact that components outside autocomplete don't have to know about anything what the autocomplete is trying to achieve.

Comment: The enhanced component might be just what I am looking for, thanks!

Comment: Looks like the Higher order component pattern I am looking for is called "Props Proxy" https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.7osq9kamo

Comment: Here's another great article if you're interested https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.95ocjl7lg